# AngularJS : deep watch for map

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I deep watch for map?

```
$scope.map = new Map();
$scope.$watch('map' function() {
   // Do Something
});
```

I would like to fire `$watch` when elements of the `$scope.map` has added or deleted or changed.

In case of object, I know I can deep watch by `$scope.$watch('obj', function(){}, true)`. But I don't know how to deep watch for map.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use `$watchCollection` instead of `$watch`.

From the [**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
> the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array
> items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a
> change is detected, the listener callback is fired.
>
> The obj collection is observed via standard $watch operation and is
> examined on every call to $digest() to see if any items have been
> added, removed, or moved.
>
> The listener is called whenever anything
> within the obj has changed. Examples include adding, removing, and
> moving items belonging to an object or array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the deep watch dont work for js Map ?

from [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) documentation :

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is
>   determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value
>   of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used.
>   This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse
>   memory and performance implications.

angular.equals work for js maps. So the deep watch should be fine with maps.